# Release nested Scripting.Dictionary with RemoveAll()

Tags: syntax, dictionary, vb6, removeall

I found here topic that answer a half of what am looking for:
[Does Scripting.Dictionary's RemoveAll() method release all of its elements first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011/does-scripting-dictionarys-removeall-method-release-all-of-its-elements-first)

In my case values are instances of a Dictionary, so I have nested hierarchy of Dictionary objects.

My question is whether I need to call RemoveAll on each sub-dictionary?

```
' just for illustration
Dim d As Dictionary
Set d = New Dictionary

Set d("a") = New Dictionary
Set d("b") = New Dictionary

' Are the next section of code necessary?
' -------------------- section start
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In d
    d.Item(key).RemoveAll
Next
' -------------------- section end

d.RemoveAll
Set d = Nothing
```

Comment: What do you mean by necessary? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to free all objects, and as I read (in the topic above), RemoveAll set all objects inside to Nothing, excellent, but am not sure if that function is recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6 all objects (via COM) are subject to reference counting and so, unless there is a cycle, you should not need to manually cater for disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code

```
Option Explicit

Private m_cCache As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' just for illustration
    Dim d As Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary

    Set d("a") = New Dictionary
    Set d("b") = New Dictionary

    d("b").Add "c", 123
    SomeMethod d

    ' Are the next section of code necessary?
    ' -------------------- section start
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In d
        d.Item(key).RemoveAll
    Next
    ' -------------------- section end

    d.RemoveAll             '--- d("b") survives
    Set d = Nothing         '--- d survives

    Debug.Print "main="; m_cCache("main").Count, "child="; m_cCache("child").Count
End Sub

Private Sub SomeMethod(d As Dictionary)
    Set m_cCache = New Collection

    m_cCache.Add d, "main"
    m_cCache.Add d("b"), "child"
End Sub
```

Without cleanup section d("b") will be virtually untouched -- neither children removed, nor instance terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you cover here is about clean up of multiple referencing, something that I know, hmm... in my case there no additional references to any of my Dictionary objects, but looking from this point, maybe you try to move me to an conclusion that I should call RemoveAll on d("a") and d("b") before d.RemoveAll, i.e. I need to inlude my code section?

Comment: It depends on the kind references you store in your `Dictionary`s. If you have something like `d("a").Add "main", d` this brings a circular reference that cannot be released without `RemoveAll` call at all. If your cleanup section is a generic function better make it use `RemoveAll` explicitly and trade performance for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I can answer myself with the next test I made.

```
Sub Main()
  Dim d As Dictionary
  Dim i, j As Integer
  Dim sDummy As String * 10000
  For i = 1 To 1000
    Set d = New Dictionary      ' root dict.
    Set d("a") = New Dictionary ' child dict.
    For j = 1 To 1000
      d("a").Add j, sDummy
    Next j
    'd("a").RemoveAll
    d.RemoveAll
    Set d = Nothing
  Next i
End Sub
```

I comment out `d("a").RemoveAll` (my child dictionary) and there no any memory leaks. That mean that calling `RemoveAll` on the root (`d`) is quite enough, and this is all that I needs to know.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you even need to call `RemoveAll` on the root level Dictionary. Releasing the last reference to it should do this by itself.

Comment: BTW I haven't fixed it in your code, but in VB6 `Dim i, j As Integer` means `Dim i As Object, j As Integer`.

Comment: @MarkHurd - Thanks for the tip about `Dim i, j As Integer`. As I'm new to VB6 I thought that both variables are Integers. Thanks again!